Problema función JavaScript cambiar color texto en Input
Estoy trabajando con PHP y Mysql. Tengo un formulario en el cual agrego información de estudiantes, mediante una función en la cual ingreso un Rut y al seleccionarlo agrega la información automáticamente en el resto de los input como por ejemplo Rut y Estado. Todo esto funciona correctamente.
Mi problema es y lo que he estado intentando hacer, es que cuando se seleccione el Rut y se cargue la información, si el estado no es igual a REGULAR, que el texto del Input nombre_estado salga en rojo, además de mostrar un mensaje de advertencia al usuario indicando que no es regular y también que el botón Enviar se deshabilite.
No soy un experto en JavaScript, pero he logrado hasta ahora cambiar el color del texto cuando ingreso directamente el dato REGULAR y lo comparo, pero no he podido capturar el dato directo desde el Input. Tampoco he logrado deshabilitar el botón.
Algo que observo, es que cuando la página carga, ya le asigno un color al texto del Input. Esto no debería ocurrir, ya que lo que necesito es que solo cambie el color del texto cuando se cargue los registros al seleccionar un Rut.
Espero una vez mas de vuestra ayuda u orientación para resolver esto.
FUNCION PARA BUSCAR DATOS
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
   $("#curso").autocomplete({
      source: "alumno.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#rut').val(ui.item.rut);
        $('#nombre_estado').val(ui.item.nombre_estado);
        $("#curso").focus();            
        }    
  });
 });
</script>

PAGINA PHP
<html>
  <body>
    <section id="container">
      <form method="post" action="row2.php" autocomplete="off" class="clearfix">
        <label for="ComprobarAlumno">Buscar</strong></label>
        <input autofocus class="form-control input-medium ui-autocomplete-input" 
        value="" autocomplete="off" id="curso" name="curso" type="text">     
                                    
        <label>Rut</label>
        <input readOnly="text" name="rut" id="rut" >
                                     
        <label>Estado</label>
        <input class="color_input" type="text" name="nombre_estado" id="nombre_estado">
                            
        <button type="submit" name="ingresar" id="ingresar">Enviar</button>         
      </form>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>

FUNCION PARA CAMBIAR COLOR INPUT Y DESHABILITAR BOTON INGRESAR
<script type="text/javascript">
  var nombre_estado = document.getElementById('nombre_estado');
  var dato = document.querySelector('input[name=nombre_estado]'); 
  var boton = document.getElementById('ingresar');

    function color() {
    if (dato == "REGULAR") 
    {
        nombre_estado.style.color = '#000000';
        console.log(dato);
        
    } else 
    {
        nombre_estado.style.color = '#FF0000';
        boton.disabled = true;
    }
   }
   nombre_estado.addEventListener('blur', color);
   color();
 </script>


A que te refieres con que no puedes capturar el dato desde el input? yo veo que lo estás tomando bien desde el script. Puedes ser más preciso sobre el momento en el que quieres capturar el dato?

Solo necesitas acceder al value, en tu variable dato almacenas el elemento del dom que seleccionaste, o sea que el valor que buscar está en dato.value

hacer console.log(ui.item) en select: function(event, ui) del autocompletado y comentar que arroja. Porque según una respuesta que te he dado, no se está cargando esa información

Lo ejecuté y trae la información correctamente. Esto funciona sin problemas.

Lo que no logró solucionar, es que a través de la función color, capture el valor del input estado y dependiendo del contenido muestre el texto en rojo o negro. Es decir, si el estado es regular muestra el texto en negro, pero si no es regular que lo muestre en rojo para advertir al usuario, y además que pueda mostrar un mensaje de alerta indicando que el Rut no es regular.

Tanto getElementById como querySelector te retornan un objeto HTML (HTMLElement), entonces cuando tienes:
 var dato = document.querySelector('input[name=nombre_estado]');
//dato es objeto

if (dato == "REGULAR") // comparas un objeto con un string

Estas comparando un objeto con un string, por lo que esa comprobación es false
Para comprobar si el valor (campo value) es igual REGULAR, haces:
if (dato.value == "REGULAR")

Además, según el esquema HTML que pones:
<input class="color_input" type="text" name="nombre_estado" id="nombre_estado">

var nombre_estado = document.getElementById('nombre_estado');
var dato = document.querySelector('input[name=nombre_estado]'); 

Tanto nombre_estado y dato obtienen el mismo elemento HTML, por lo que uno de ellos te está sobraando
const nombre_estado = document.getElementById('nombre_estado');
const boton = document.getElementById('ingresar');

function color() {
  if (nombre_estado.value == "REGULAR") 
  {
     nombre_estado.style.color = '#000000';
     console.log(dato);
  } 
  else 
  {
     nombre_estado.style.color = '#FF0000';
     boton.disabled = true;
  }
}

Aquí un ejemplo completo:


const source = [
{rut: '111111', nombre_estado: "REGULAR"},
{rut: '222222', nombre_estado: "OTRO"},
]

$("#curso").autocomplete({
  source:  source.map(a=>a.rut),
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const item = source.find(a=>ui.item.value == a.rut)
    $('#curso').val(item.rut);
    $('#rut').val(item.rut);
    $('#nombre_estado').val(item.nombre_estado);
    $("#curso").focus();
       
    
    color(); // ESTO te falta, debes llamar a la función
  }
});

const nombre_estado = document.getElementById('nombre_estado');
const boton = document.getElementById('ingresar');

function color() {
  if (nombre_estado.value == "REGULAR") 
  {
     nombre_estado.style.color = '#000000';
  } 
  else 
  {
     nombre_estado.style.color = '#FF0000';
     boton.disabled = true;
     alert("Rut no regular"); 
  }
}
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-Fb0zP4jE3JHqu+IBB9YktLcSjI1Zc6J2b6gTjB0LpoM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="post" action="row2.php" autocomplete="off" class="clearfix">
  <label for="ComprobarAlumno">Buscar</label>
  <input autofocus class="form-control input-medium ui-autocomplete-input" value="" autocomplete="off" id="curso" name="curso" type="text">

  <label>Rut</label>
  <input readOnly="text" name="rut" id="rut">

  <label>Estado</label>
  <input class="color_input" type="text" name="nombre_estado" id="nombre_estado">

  <button type="submit" name="ingresar" id="ingresar">Enviar</button>
</form>




Agradezco tu respuesta y ayuda. Aplique los cambios, pero ocurre que aun lo logro realizar correctamente la validación, ya que trae tanto en estado REGULAR como otros estados en rojo, además de eso aun no se deshabilita el botón.

@SBK22 Antes del if agrega console.log(nombre_estado.value ) y me dices que imprime en la consola

Lo agregue y antes de buscar un Rut muestra , después de seleccionar el Rut no muestra nada.

@SBK22 Pero tu función se ejecuta luego de perder el foco nombre_estado.addEventListener('blur', color); no al seleccionar el rut. Estas teniendo en cuenta eso?

@SBK22 Estoy casi seguro que lo anterior es tu problema. Tu tienes que la función se active cuando pierde el foco, no cuando se llena el autocompletado para lo cual basta con llamar a la función color() ahí dentro. Te dejé un ejemplo completo para que lo pruebes

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estaba un poco confundido, pero con tus indicaciones funciona correctamente, te agradezco tu tiempo e interés para resolver mi problema.

Entonces si era lo que pensaba ! rahos, debi haber respondido antes.

El problema en el código se debe a la falta de conocimiento básico en JavaScript. Se han declarado dos formas diferentes de seleccionar el mismo input:
var nombre_estado = document.getElementById('nombre_estado');
var dato = document.querySelector('input[name=nombre_estado]');

Aunque estas variables apuntan al mismo elemento, no hacen nada útil en la función dentro de ella la condición:
if (dato == "REGULAR")

no pierde totalmente el sentido, ya que está comparando el propio elemento HTML con una cadena, lo cual es incorrecto.
Lo correcto sería comparar el valor del input, usando:
nombre_estado.value == "REGULAR"

Así, el código verificaría correctamente si el texto digitado en el input es REGULAR.

La propuesta para resolver es la siguiente:

Una función status para verificar si el valor digitado en el campo de input es REGULAR. Si lo es, se habilitará el botón; de lo contrario, el botón quedará deshabilitado y el borde del campo será rojo. La función se activa cada vez que se escribe en el campo nombre_estado, la palabra REGULAR.


 

const nombre_estado = document.getElementById('nombre_estado');
const boton = document.getElementById('ingresar');

 
function estado(regular) {

  return {
    regular,
    funcionValidadora() {
      
      const color = () => {
        if (nombre_estado.value.trim().toUpperCase() === this.regular.toUpperCase()) {
          boton.disabled = false;  
          nombre_estado.style.borderColor = '';
        } else {
          boton.disabled = true; 
          nombre_estado.style.borderColor = '#FF0000';
          
        }
      };

      
      nombre_estado.addEventListener('input', color);
      boton.disabled = true; 
      color();
    }
  };
}

const functor = estado("REGULAR");
functor.funcionValidadora(); 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="container">
      <form method="post" action="row2.php" autocomplete="off" class="clearfix">
        <label for="ComprobarAlumno">Buscar</strong></label>
        <input autofocus class="form-control input-medium ui-autocomplete-input" 
        value="" autocomplete="off" id="curso" name="curso" type="text">     
                                    
        <label>Rut</label>
        <input readOnly="text" name="rut" id="rut" >
                                     
        <label>Estado</label>
        <input class="color_input" type="text" name="nombre_estado" id="nombre_estado">
                            
        <button type="submit" name="ingresar" id="ingresar">Enviar</button>         
      </form>
    </section>



En detalle, el código, la función estado recibe un parámetro regular y retorna un objeto.
La propiedad regular almacenará el valor y el método funcionValidadora gestiona la validación de la entrada.
Dentro del método funcionValidadora, la función interna llamada color compara el valor del campo de entrada (nombre_estado) con el valor de la variable regular y, si los valores son iguales, el botón se habilita.
Y el event listener inicia la función color siempre que se escribe.
Finalizando con la instancia, al llamar a estado("REGULAR"), se crea un nuevo objeto y se invoca la función funcionValidadora para iniciar la validación.
